# How to make <input type="file" /> editable?

Tags: html, file, input

I have found some examples that explains how to make input type=file to be non editable.
like `<input type="file" onkeydown="blur()" />`

But I made test application in Visual Studio and find out that `<input type="file" />` in non editable by default.

How to make it editable?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "editable"?

Comment: What do you mean by 'editable'?

Comment: That user can manually enter path to file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior of `<input type="file">` elements is very strictly controlled by browsers, and you cannot force them to do anything other than what they want to do.  Generally, modern browsers will only allow a file picker to be used for selecting a file for upload. Your Javascript code can't set the value and can't see anything more than the tail file name (the name without prefixing directory names).

Comment: I don not want to set value with javascript, just to enable manual entering of file path. thanks

Comment: You cannot do that reliably. Modern browsers simply do not allow manual filename entry - the user is **only** allowed to use the native file picker widget.

Answer (score 2):

The following jquery plugin can help in making a intput type="File" editable.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle