# Fill input file form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-input, file-io

> **Note:**
>
> The answer(s) below reflect the state of legacy browsers in 2009. Now you can actually set the value of the file input element dynamically/programatically using JavaScript in 2017.
>
> See the answer in this question for details as well as a demo:
> [How to set file input value programatically (i.e.: when drag-dropping files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47515232/584192)

I need to fill an HTML form with JavaScript to set the path of a file for upload it. The web that this form belongs to, already has a visual upload implemented, but

```
<form id="mobile_fileform">
    <input type="file" style="height: 20px; width: 0px; opacity: 0; " id="mobile_fileselect1" multiple="" size="-17">
    <input type="file" style="height: 20px; width: 0px; opacity: 0; " id="mobile_fileselect2" multiple="" size="-17">
    <input type="file" style="height: 20px; width: 0px; opacity: 0; " id="mobile_fileselect3" multiple="" size="-17">
</form>
```

How can I set the path of the file in this form and how can I upload it using JavaScript?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate [stackoverflow.com/questions/4286782/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286782/how-to-make-input-type-file-editable)...

Comment: For security reasons, it is not possible to manually add and upload a file in a file input control with JavaScript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **value** property of `input:file` is **read-only** for security reasons. If you want to set it, you'll need to do it server-side.

As a result, what you're asking to do is **not possible**. Consider the implications: any webpage would be able to upload any file from someone's computer, so long as they knew the path.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Read this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a#answer-47172409

Comment: <input type="file" />

<script>
    // Get a reference to our file input
    const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

    // Create a new File object
    const myFile = new File(['Hello World!'], 'myFile.txt', {
        type: 'text/plain',
        lastModified: new Date(),
    });

    // Now let's create a DataTransfer to get a FileList
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    dataTransfer.items.add(myFile);
    fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
</script>