# Creating <input> fields from dragged images

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I dragged two images onto an HTML5 page. I see the preview. Now I want to submit them to the server WITHOUT using the FormData object (for compatibility reasons).

HTML file

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <img id="image1"/>
    <img id="image2"/>
    <form id="myform" action="otherpage.php" method="post">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

After dragging two images onto the page, I see their previews in **image1** and **image2**. In the debugger, I see that the src for image1 is `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ...`
and the src for image2 is `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA...`

Using javascript, I want to submit those two images to otherpage.php. My idea is to create  fields, and use their values as the source of the image.

```js
function sendImages() {
var placeForm = document.getElementById('myform');
var textInput; //Create a local object
textInput = document.createElement('input'); //Create first <input> object
textInput.name='file1';
textInput.value=document.getElementById('image1').src; //Assign value to object
placeForm.appendChild(textInput); //Append object to form

textInput = document.createElement('input'); //Create second <input> object
textInput.name='file2';
textInput.value=document.getElementById('image2').src; //Assign value to object
placeForm.appendChild(textInput); //Append object to form

placeForm.submit(); //Send form

}
```

This results in an enormous memory hit that is cleared only when I shut down the browser or after displaying `about:blank`.

Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried setting `type` of the input element?

Comment: Setting the `type` to `text` doesn't help; that is the default after createElement and in any event still results in the memory hit. Setting the `type` to `file` might be a good idea. Will try that.

Comment: Actually, setting the input type to `file` didn't work for me, and this explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763941/fill-input-file-form-with-javascript

Comment: have you tried send to server as data/json not as formdata ?