# Save input file contents to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**Is it possible to set a variable for an input file element value, so it could further be assigned to another input?**
This is, how it works with text inputs:

```
var tempValue = document.getElementById('text').value;
```

Comment: Yes you can get the value but you cann't set it.

Comment: Do you mean the contents of the file, or the value (filepath) of a file input?

Comment: @eisbehr you can read filename, and the contents (but no the path) – for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is a popular question, so you can find it at these links ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763941/fill-input-file-form-with-javascript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)).

But no, it is impossible – value property of `input:file` is read-only for security reasons – you can do it only on server-side.
To read contents of the file, you have to use `FileReader` and specify how to read content (as plain text, as binary, or as a Blob) – [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) of reading as a Blob.