# Fill input file with javascript

Tags: jquery, file-upload, submit, webcam, form-data

I saw here: [Fill input file form with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763941/fill-input-file-form-with-javascript) that it is not possible to change the value manually of an input file. And I understand the security reason, we don't want the webpage to be able to upload any file of the user.

But in the meantime, I see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects that you can send files if you have it in JavaScript as long as the file is a `File` object.

And I have the `File` object in JavaScript. So, is there a way to avoid the use of `XMLHttpRequest` and use the normal form to send the `File`? I want to avoid JavaScript to send the file (which is in the JavaScript memory and not on the user disk).